# How to insert node in TreeView as the first one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have tree view structure , and I need to implement function:

```
public void InsertNodeAtTheBeginning(TreeView tree, TreeNode node)
{
  tree.Nodes.Add_(node); // node should be added as tree.Nodes[0]
}
```

And every other nodes should be offset: `tree.Nodes[1]`...`tree.Nodes[tree.Nodes.Count + 1]`.
All nodes in the tree have `.Level` property is equal to `0` ( so it's like a list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `TreeView.Nodes.Insert(0, ...)`